# Why SafeArea frame size is changing?

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode9

After I added an UIView into one of my UIViewController I noticed SafeArea size is shortened from bottom about 40 and when I select the UIViewController it applies the effect all other UIViewControllers. When I click any other UIViewController, all displays back the SafeArea to its original size excluding the UIView added.

I deleted the UIView I added and see if it going to fix the issue but it did not.

More info about setup: UIViewController's UIViews are separated into three parts. Header-Content-Footer. All of their items has UIStackViews. I added the UIView into Content view.

When I run simulator I don't see any gap in the bottom, it looks as I intended.

Please let me know, if you need any more information/clarification.

**EDIT:** I noticed I have two SafeArea inside the UIViewController. Do not how this happened and how to remove one created under Content UIView.

**EDIT 2:** Here is the photo of the duplicate SafeArea in the StoryBoard.

[image: Duplicate SafeArea]

Answer (score 0):

I created another UIViewController and copied the content needed there.